# How to show spinner until component is mounted in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I have a List component which takes some time to be loaded.

I want it to show a spinner until it is loaded and mounted but unfortunately everything I try does not work.

I am trying to do something like this:

```
class List extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isReady: false,
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({isReady: true});
    }

    render() {
        if(this.state.isReady){
            return (
                <Content>
                    {this.renderList()}
                </Content>
            );
        }
        else {
            return (
                <Spinner/>
            );
        }

    }

    renderList() {
        return this.props.data.map((item, index) => {
            return (
                <ListItem type={this.props.type} text={item} key={index}/>
            );
        });
    }
}
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: How do you receive this.props.data?

Comment: @ChristopherNgo sending a static array to the data prop

Answer (score 1):

You should be checking both the props.data and the state.isReady in a case where you don't know which would come first:

```
    render() {
        if(this.state.isReady && this.props.data.length !== 0){
            return (
                <Content>
                    {this.renderList()}
                </Content>
            );
        }
        else {
            return (
                <Spinner/>
            );
        }

    }
```

Comment: Then maybe your app is too fast haha

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code that you put up here. If there's an issue, it can be with the Spinner or Content components.

Comment: No, it take 1-2 seconds to load but it loads on an empty screen - the spinner is simply not there

Comment: My bad. Added `this.props.data.length !== 0`. Try now?

Comment: if(!this.state.isReady) shows the spinner normally. the spinner is ok

Comment: data.length is never = 0. it is static and hardcoded array.

Comment: Then the delay is in your Content or ListItem component. Can you add those too?

Comment: You are right, the delay is in to loop rendering the ListItem. But I don't care about the delay. I just want to show a spinner when it is loading...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should init `isLoading` state to be `true` in `constructor`, then set it to `false` in `componentDidMount`.

Then try to `render <Spinner />` while `isLoading` is `true`

Comment: did not help :(

Comment: What’s happening, bro?